How to update PHP version of laravel project on CPanel and WHM
I updated the server thus the default php version has been upgraded from 7.4 to 8.0
That caused some of old packages not working and I did some updates
After changing the code I ran
composer update
composer install

However after that when I visit the url, I get
Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.2".

I tried this.
In WHM, PHPMultiManager->Domains found my domain and choosed ea-php8.0 from ea-php7.4
And also ran
/opt/cpanel/ea-php80/root/usr/bin/php /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer update
/opt/cpanel/ea-php80/root/usr/bin/php /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer install


Does this help? Or this?
